# como hago un buscador que encuentre un div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

tengo el buscador de mi web pero solo busca en una dirección, ejemplo www.mipagina.com/search ,, esto no lo puedo modificar... tengo un div que lleva imagenes y texto dentro, y necesito crear un buscador que pueda encontrarlo y mostrar el contenido ,como lo hago?

**este es el codigo que necesito que encuentre el buscador**

```
<div class='contenedor'>
<div class='fondo'/>
<img class='app' src=''/>
<button class='vista'></button>
<div class='centrado'></div></div>
```

Comment: O sea, quieres que al entrar a un enlace baje hasta un lugar específico de la página?

Comment: quiero que por ejemplo al buscar una palabra aparezca el div

Comment: Quieres algo así? El nombre y profesión pueden simular tu contenedor y el resto de divs que tengas: http://jsfiddle.net/891nvajb/9/